# How to push GitLab build statusses to a GitHub website repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, hook, gitlab-ci-runner

### Objective

Upon completing a GitLab runner CI build (of a mirror of a GitHub repository), I would like automatically to push the build status badge to a GitHub website.

### Approach I

My first thought would be include a shell script inside the `.gitlab-ci.yml` that gets the build status of "the commit", and clones the GitHub status website repository, and updates/adds the build status (through a git add,commit, push).

However, a more practical issue with this approach is that the build status of "the commit" will not be published until the CI is done. So the script inside the yml might not be able to get that latest build status. I imagine however, some argument like `post` or whatever allows a workaround for that. A second issue would be that it would pollute the original repository, and it would break the CI for other people that do not have `push` credentials to the "GitHub status website repository".

### Approach II

My second option was to create a local shell script that monitors the GitLab server build statusses, and pushes the new build status badge to the "GitHub status website repository". However, I would expect there are options/tools in GitLab that are designed to do this.

### Approach III

So my third guess would be to use some hook-script in GitLab, yet I did not quite figure out how use the Gitlab-API wrapper to create the hook that pushes the build status of GitLab repository `gitlab_mirror_repo`, which is a mirror of `github_repository`, to `github_build_status_website`.

### Question

Hence, I would like to ask: *how can I push the build status `.svg` of my own GitLab CI Runner on GitLab repository `gitlab_mirror_repo` to a GitHub repository named `github_build_status_website` (by means of my local GitHub ssh-key)?*

### Notes

- I am aware of [GitLab's GitHub integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ci_cd_for_external_repos/github_integration.html), however currently not in a position to afford it.
- One can ignore what content should be in the `github_build_status_website` repository, if it only contains the `.svg` I'll be able to build a website around it.

Comment: are you able to embed the status bade in the README ? should work if you're able to publicly access that at all

Comment: Hi, that is part of the xy-problem, I am not able to embed the build status badge of the GitLab server on the GitHub website, because it runs only locally and on tor. However, I am able to push the GitLab build status badge to my GitHub website repository from the local GitLab server. And I assume I am able to embed the build status `.svg` from that GitHub hosted website, on README's of other GitHub repositories.